# Should a comma be included when listing age?

Tags: adjectives, commas, writing, phrasing, reference

When listing age under someone's name for reference, does there need to be a comma between "age" and the number?

My company is running an ad for a beauty supplement featuring our brand ambassador for the product. The main image is a headshot of our ambassador with her name and her age listed below.

In my specific example, should her age be written:
A) Age, 62
or
B) Age 62 ?

We generally use Chicago, but it seems like there wouldn't be a difference across the different styles.

Comment: Hi J, welcome to EL&U. There are two issues with your post: firstly, punctuation tends to be a matter of *style*, so the stock answer would be: "do what your publisher's style guide recommends, or if you don't have a style guide as reference, find one on the internet and adopt it." Secondly, I *think* I understand the context, but it's not really clear: I recommend you add more detail, e.g. by expanding the example to show exactly how it relates to the previous line(s) in the text. For further guidance, see [ask]. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No comma in *your example*. I've seen examples like this:

> *Joe Brown, age 57, CEO of Brown Industries Co.*
>
> *Jane Jones, age 62, Founder & President Jane, Inc.*

Or you could omit age and have

> *Participants were three males (ages 30, 31, 46), and two females (ages 31 and 35).*